# Website Not Redirecting to the Specified Page Upon Login

Tags: html, css, python-3.x, flask, bootstrap-4

Good Evening,

I am presently attempting to develop a website using Python and Flask.  I have found a number of resources that have proved useful, however, I have hit a wall when it comes to creating a login for the website.

I have hard coded logic to authenticate the user and if successful redirect them to another page (dashboard), if unsuccessful the user is prompted to try signing in again.  For some reason, neither of these things happen when I test the logic on the website.

As you can see I have created a style.css file, but I would be interested in knowing if there is a better way to achieve the same outcome using Bootstrap, which I intend using for the rest of the site.  I am not sure if there is a best practice for integrating the styles within this file into the bootstrap framework.

In addition, I have been attempting to use the flash functionality to display the username and password for testing purposes, however, have been unable to get this to work either.

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

**Login.html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style.css" type="text/css">
{% block body %}
{% if session['logged_in'] %}
<p>You're logged in already!</p>
{% else %}


<form action="/login" method="POST">
    <div class="login">
        <div class="login-screen">
            <div class="app-title">
                <h1>Login</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="login-form">
                <div class="control-group">
                    <input type="text" class="login-field" value="" placeholder="email address" name="email" value="{{request.form.email}}">
                        <label class="login-field-icon fui-user" for="login-name"></label>
                </div>

                <div class="control-group">
                    <input type="password" class="login-field" value="" placeholder="password" name="password" value="{{request.form.password}}">
                        <label class="login-field-icon fui-lock" for="login-pass"></label>
                </div>

                <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block" >
                    <br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<p> {{error}} </p>

{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

**__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, request, session, abort, url_for
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    if not session.get('logged_in'):
        return render_template('login.html')
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))

@app.route('/dashboard/')
def dashboard():
    return  ("dashboard.html")

@app.route('/login/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def do_admin_login():

    error = ''
    try:
        if request.method == "POST":
            attempted_email = request.form['email']
            attempted_password = request.form['password']

            flash(attempted_email)
            flash(attempted_password)

            if attempted_password == 'password' and attempted_email == 'admin':
                return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
            else:
                error = "Invalid credentials. Please try again"

        return render_template(login.html, error = error)

    except Exception as e:
            return render_template("login.html", error = error)

@app.route("/logout/")
def logout():
    session['logged_in'] = False
    return home()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

**style.css**

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*:focus {
    outline: none;
}
body {
    font-family: Arial;
    background-color: #D3600A;
    padding: 50px;
}
.login {
    margin: 20px auto;
    width: 300px;
}
.login-screen {
    background-color: #FFF;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px
}

.app-title {
    text-align: center;
    color: #777;
}

.login-form {
    text-align: center;
}
.control-group {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

input {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ECF0F1;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 200;
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 250px;
    transition: border .5s;
}

input:focus {
    border: 2px solid #D3600A;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.btn {
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    background: #D3600A;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 25px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: none;
    transition: 0.25s;
    display: block;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.btn:hover {
    background-color: #2980B9;
}

.login-link {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #444;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have hard coded logic to authenticate the user and if successful
>   redirect them to another page (dashboard), if unsuccessful the user is
>   prompted to try signing in again. For some reason, neither of these
>   things happen when I test the logic on the website.

The problem is likely in your indentation:

def do_admin_login():

```
error = ''
try:
    if request.method == "POST":
        attempted_email = request.form['email']
        attempted_password = request.form['password']

        flash(attempted_email)
        flash(attempted_password)

        if attempted_password == 'password' and attempted_email == 'admin':
            return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
        else:
            error = "Invalid credentials. Please try again"
            return render_template('login.html', error = error)

   return render_template('login.html')

except Exception as e:
        return render_template("login.html", error = error)
```

The first `return render_template` is when there is an error. The second return is when the request is a `GET` instead.
**Note also you have to put quote your template in `render_template`**

> In addition, I have been attempting to use the flash functionality to
>   display the username and password for testing purposes, however, have
>   been unable to get this to work either.

As far as I know, you should pass a string instead to `flash`
Like this: `flash('You have been logged in')

> As you can see I have created a style.css file, but I would be
>   interested in knowing if there is a better way to achieve the same
>   outcome using Bootstrap, which I intend using for the rest of the
>   site. I am not sure if there is a best practice for integrating the
>   styles within this file into the bootstrap framework.

You can use [flask bootstrap](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Bootstrap/)

and also:

```
def dashboard():
    return  ("dashboard.html")
```

should be:

```
def dashboard():
    return render_template("dashboard.html")
```

For flashing your message, try doing so just before you return.

```
if attempted_password == 'password' and attempted_email == 'admin':
                flash(attempted_password)
                flash(attempted_email)
                return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
            else:
                error = "Invalid credentials. Please try again"
                return render_template(login.html, error = error)
```

Comment: Hi Mekicha.  Thank you for your contribution and the time taken to craft an answer.  When trying to implement suggestion 1 my code errors saying that the indentation at line 19 is a problem.  I changed the code back to the original indentation and the issue is resolved.  Regarding suggestion 2, I have witnessed flash being used to display the value of a variable, hence why my the argument isn't quoted.  I have tried hard coding the string, however, this didn't. resolve the issue either.  Do you have any other throughts?

Comment: Try flash` just before you render your template and see what it gives. I updated my answer to reflect how that change might look